# Inheritance or Object Slicing?

Tags: c++, inheritance, object-slicing, constructor-chaining

I've read up so much on this, and can't figure out why my `Player` object is losing its `draw` function.

Object class:

```
class Object {
    public:
        Object(){}

        Object(Object* o){
            o->draw();
        }

        virtual void draw() { cout << "Object draw" << endl; }
};
```

Player class:

```
class Player : public Object {
    public:
        Player() : Object(this) {}

        void draw(){ cout << "Player draw" << endl; }
};
```

When I run this code:

```
int main(){
    Object o;
    Player p;
}
```

The output is: `Object draw`. I expect it to be `Player draw` so the object is either not overriding or the object is getting sliced when it goes through the function.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Sorry, missed a semicolon and  a couple colons when I copied it over

Comment: Prefer a simple copy-paste instead of re-writing it to avoid any typos.